# how to use google cloud speech API

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-speech-api

I am new to use the google API's. I am trying to use the google speech recognition, to convert my speech to text and vise versa. But don't know how to use the google speech API. I download the google cloud package using this command

```
composer require google/cloud
```

But I dont know how to use this. I am following tutorial https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php from this link.
but it showing me errors.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Cloud\Exception\ServiceException: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information in /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php:221
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php(185): Google\Cloud\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(DomainException))
#1 /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php(167): Google\Cloud\RequestWrapper->fetchCredentials()
#2 /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php(150): Google\Cloud\RequestWrapper->getToken()
#3 /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php(131): Google\Cloud\RequestWrapper->signRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
#4 /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RestTrait.php(78): Google\Cloud\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#5 /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/goo in /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php on line 221
```

Comment: And what happens when you follow the link given to you in the message itself?  ---> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials

Comment: I did not getting any thing. I just getting the above errors.

Comment: Go though creating the credentials tutorial again.  Your code cant read it.

Answer (score 0):

First things first it looks like you need to generate your service account credentials :).

Please take a look at this guide in order to get that set up: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/latest/guides/authentication

From there you'll want to do the following:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

// Pass the key file directly into your client.
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/service/credentials.json'
]);

// OR

// Store the key file as an environment variable
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service/credentials.json');

$storage = new StorageClient();
```

Comment: Thanks David S for replying

Comment: I enables all the api thats given on the link provided bu you. but after that i am getting error Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Cloud\Exception\ServiceException: {
 "error": "deleted_client",
 "error_description": "The OAuth client was deleted."
}
 in /var/www/html/googlevoice/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php:219

Comment: Interesting! I would recommend regenerating your service account credentials if you haven't tried that yet. If that doesn't work, I would reach out to the support team directly - https://cloud.google.com/support/